# What happens if you try to utilize TPL on a computer with a single core?

Tags: c#, .net, multiprocessing, task-parallel-library

Title does justice.

I'm building an application that uses TPL instead of Backgroundworker, but I'm wondering what might happen if you try to run TPL on a machine that doesn't use multi-core cpus.

Are there any compatibility issues? Performance slow-downs? Or does application go boom?

Comment: IMHO, it's key to keep in mind the different goals of asynchrony and concurrency.  If there's only 1 core that your threads can be scheduled on (which could be due to multiple reasons, not just the physical CPU's in the machine), then that will limit your concurrency (in terms of operations happening on multiple cores in parallel), but TPL is still a big "win" with asynchrony in such a situation, since it allows you to not block a thread waiting for an oepration to complete.  For instance, you can still do N parallel HTTP calls on a single-core machine thanks to asynchrony. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues, no measurable slow-down. Of course also no speed-up for CPU-bound tasks. TPL adapts automatically to the number of available cores.

Answer (score 2):

A singe-core PC can still do threading.

Everything should work normally, with the ThreadPool creating a very low number of threads (1 or 2 by default).

You still pay for the overhead of TPL but you will not normally get any benefits.